# pdfx + embedall

Tags: embedding, pdfx

I quite like the idea of two things:

- PDF/A complience
- embedding TeX source in the PDF

Hence I'm trying to do this

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[a-3u,pdf17]{pdfx}
% todo: update options when 2019 version of package aquired
\RequirePackage[source]{embedall}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Hi \(a + b = c\)}

\section{Hi \texorpdfstring{\(a + b = c\)}{a+b=c}}

\end{document}
```

### Issue

Unfortunately, while `pdfx` by itself produces a compliant PDF (with the PDF/A-3U validation profile), when `embedall` is added veraPDF reports a few errors.
It'd be nice to get this working :)

[image]

Comment: It is on the todo-list, see https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/37

Comment: Wow. I would have never known to look there.

Comment: But while the bug is almost solved in `embedfile`, `embedall` still does not transmit the `/AFRelationship` value. In the meanwhile you can embed your sources manually using `\embedfile`.